# Features by Playwright Test Runner

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

Here is a quick question and seeking some clarifications reg the documentation provided by playwright.
Here are my queries:

the features mentioned under the "Playwright test" section of the documentation are available only when someone use playwright Test as test runner only ?

if someone is using a different test runner. eg : cucymber.js , the same features is not accessible directly (although with some extra codes , these features might be still possible)?

please help me understand if the above are true.

Comment: Not sure, but seems you are mixing features from cucumber and fixtures from playwright?

Comment: @GajJulije my post was regarding on the clarification whether the features mentioned under the "playwright tests" sections can be achieved ONLY when testRunner provided by playwright is used (which i think is the right statement).